# Adding custom taxonomy in my existing category URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, urls

I have a custom taxonomy for my posts called "Continents" and they could be:

Europe, Africa, Antarctica etc...

Then I have standard categories like: News, Reviews, Interviews etc.

And 1 subcategory for some categories e.g. for News I have subcategories like (entertainment, politics, sport, science etc.)

My question is how to set up URL permalinks in WordPress so I have these types of links for "categories":

```
http://example.com/africa/news/politics
http://example.com/europe/reviews
http://example.com/antarctica
```

but at the same time I need to access things like:

```
http://example.com/news/politics
```

that will include everything from these categories and not taking care of the Continents taxonomy item.

And at that same time I need to access the posts (details) like:

```
http://example.com/2013/12/17/conflict-in-kongo-continues
```

Could that be done via WordPress or some plugin?

Comment: Any idea if it could be done or mixing taxnomy 1 with taxonomy 2(first level) and taxonomy 2(second level) and having a custom detail link that includes the date is not possible to achieve in WP?

Comment: How to do that?